# Error generating Entity Wrapper in Visual Studio 2013 with CRM developer tools

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I have this problem with Visual Studio. I followed a guide to install the CRM developer tools in Visual Studio 2013 (it is normally compatible only with Visual Studio 2010 or 2012).

Others don't have this problem when they use this tool on Visual Studio 2013. When I try to generate an entity wrapper, I have an error:

> impossible to find specific file.

Here is an image of this problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the initial entity file is deleted before generating entity wrapper.
This is what help me.